# How do I join 2 tables in LibreOffice Calc?

Tags: libreoffice, vlookup

I looked up one of the other answers here but it's not helping me. I have 2 sheets and I'm trying to join 2 columns from my Sheet2 to my Sheet1 by joining on a common column-

Sheet1-

[image]

Sheet2-

[image]

When entering the `VLOOKUP` function in the image 1, the cell shows `#NAME?` and when I hover over the function it just displays a message like `VLOOKUP(> Search criterion, Array, Index, Sort order): The value to be found in the first column.`

Comment: Maybe your local setting require `;` instead of `,` as the delimiter.

Comment: i tried `=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!AH2;Sheet2!A:B;2;0)` but even that's not working

Comment: What happens now?

Comment: @AlexM not working...

Comment: Do your get an error?  what is the error?

Comment: @ScottCraner the cell shows `#NAME?` and when I hover over the function it just displays a message like `VLOOKUP(> Search criterion, Array, Index, Sort order): The value to be found in the first column.`

Comment: then I do not know, unless you are using a different language pack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, it turns out my logic was right, but the syntax it expected was different.

LibreOffice uses a different notation to call ranges on other sheets than Excel. Different versions of LibreOffice might also expect different syntax.

This was the VLOOKUP syntax that I ended up using-

For REGION: `=VLOOKUP(AH2,$Sheet2.A:B,2,0)`

For SUB_REGION: `=VLOOKUP(AH2,$Sheet2.A:C,3,0)`

Comment: So, the answer is that LibreOffice uses a slightly different notation to call ranges on other sheets than Excel does? Would be most useful to future users to explicitly explain that in this answer.

Comment: @AlexM And this notation might also be different for different versions of LibreOffice. I saw an old answer whose notation didn't help me in this case. Hopefully my answer is the latest one for everyone out there.

Comment: +1 to the Q and the A from me at this point. Thanks for staying active on your question and helping create useful content